# 401 Error Unknown authorization retrieving Google calendars

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, oauth, google-api

When I execute a CalendarService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer()); I get an OAuthException 401 Error Unknown authorization header.

I'm using GWT+GAE I don't know why I'm receiving this error, oauthParameters seem to be OK.

1. I get user login on
   loginService.login
2. I check if I have
   the authentication already on
   oauthService.checkOauthTokenSecret
3. If not, I'll do a redirect to Google
   Aproval page for GCalendar
   permission
4. I get querystring
   returned by Google and I get Access
   Token and Access Token Secret and
   set it to the user entity for later
   use on oauthService.upgradeLogin.
5. And trying to get calendars on
   oauthService.getPublicCalendars.

I'm using MVP pattern with mvp4g framework, sorry if is a bit confusing 0:-)

Any idea why I'm receiving 401 error? I think is something about I'm going up & down through client and server and external pages... and something is missing :-( but all parameters seem to be correctly fullfilled.

Client side

```
public void onStart(){
    GWT.log("onStart");
    loginService.login(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(), new AsyncCallback<LoginInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginInfo result) {
            Common.loginInfo = result;
            if(Common.loginInfo.isLoggedIn()) { 
                oauthService.checkOauthTokenSecret(new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) {
                        if (result == null){
                            eventBus.OauthLogin();
                        }else{
                            oauthService.upgradeLogin(Window.Location.getQueryString(),Common.loginInfo, new AsyncCallback<LoginInfo>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(LoginInfo result) {
                                    Common.loginInfo = result;
                                    getCitas();
                                }
                                @Override public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                    Common.handleError(caught);                         
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    @Override public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        Common.handleError(caught);                         
                    }
                });
            }else{
                eventBus.LoadLogin();
            }
        }
        @Override public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Common.handleError(caught);
        }
    });
}
```

Server Side

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.GoogleOAuthHelper;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.GoogleOAuthParameters;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthException;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthHmacSha1Signer;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthParameters;
import com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService;
import com.google.gdata.data.calendar.CalendarEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.calendar.CalendarFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import com.rdt.citas.client.OAuthoritzationService;
import com.rdt.citas.client.shared.LoginInfo;

public class OAuthoritzationServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet 
implements OAuthoritzationService {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OAuthoritzationServiceImpl.class.getName());

private static String KEY_PARAM = "oauth_consumer_key";
private static String SECRET_PARAM = "oauth_consumer_secret";
private static String SCOPE_PARAM = "scope_calendars";
private static String CALLBACK_PARAM = "oauth_callback";


public String checkOauthTokenSecret(){

    ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
    getOauthParams(context);

    return (String) this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("oauthTokenSecret");;
}

public String getApprovalOAuthPageURL() throws IOException{

    ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
    getOauthParams(context);

    GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();

    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(getFromSession(KEY_PARAM));
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(getFromSession(SECRET_PARAM));
    oauthParameters.setScope(getFromSession(SCOPE_PARAM));
    oauthParameters.setOAuthCallback(getFromSession(CALLBACK_PARAM));
    GoogleOAuthHelper oauthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

    try {                       
        oauthHelper.getUnauthorizedRequestToken(oauthParameters);

        String approvalPageUrl = oauthHelper.createUserAuthorizationUrl(oauthParameters);
        String oauthTokenSecret = oauthParameters.getOAuthTokenSecret();

        this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().setAttribute("oauthTokenSecret", oauthTokenSecret);

        return approvalPageUrl;

    } catch (OAuthException e) {
        log.log(Level.WARNING,e.toString());
        return "";
    } finally{
    }

}

public LoginInfo upgradeLogin(String queryString, LoginInfo login){
    // receiving '?key1=value1&key2=value2
    queryString = queryString.substring(1, queryString.length());
    String k = getFromSession(KEY_PARAM);
    String s = getFromSession(SECRET_PARAM);

    GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(k);
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(s);

    String oauthTS = (String) this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("oauthTokenSecret");//oauthParameters.getOAuthTokenSecret();
    oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(oauthTS);

    GoogleOAuthHelper oauthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
    oauthHelper.getOAuthParametersFromCallback(queryString,oauthParameters);

    login.setQueryStringTokens(queryString);
    login.setAccessTokenSecret(oauthTS);

    try {
        String accesToken = oauthHelper.getAccessToken(oauthParameters);
        login.setTokenSecret(accesToken);
    } catch (OAuthException e) {
        log.log(Level.WARNING,e.toString());
    }
    return login;
} 

public ArrayList<String> getPublicCalendars(String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret){
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    CalendarFeed calendarResultFeed = null;

    GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(getFromSession(KEY_PARAM));
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(getFromSession(SECRET_PARAM));
    oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(accessToken);
    oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);            
    oauthParameters.setOAuthType(OAuthParameters.OAuthType.THREE_LEGGED_OAUTH);
    oauthParameters.setScope(getFromSession(SCOPE_PARAM));

    CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");                  

    try {
        myService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
        URL calendarFeedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
        calendarResultFeed = myService.getFeed(calendarFeedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);
    } catch (OAuthException e) {
        log.info("OAuthException");
        log.log(Level.WARNING,e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.info("MalformedURLException");
        log.log(Level.WARNING,e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.info("IOException");
        log.log(Level.WARNING,e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        log.info("ServiceException");
        log.log(Level.WARNING,e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (calendarResultFeed != null && calendarResultFeed.getEntries() != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < calendarResultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
            CalendarEntry entry = calendarResultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
            result.add(entry.getTitle().getPlainText());              
        } 
    }
    return result;
}


private void getOauthParams(ServletContext context) {
    this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()
        .setAttribute(KEY_PARAM, context.getInitParameter(KEY_PARAM));
    this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()
        .setAttribute(SECRET_PARAM, context.getInitParameter(SECRET_PARAM));
    this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()
        .setAttribute(SCOPE_PARAM, context.getInitParameter(SCOPE_PARAM));
    this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()
        .setAttribute(CALLBACK_PARAM, context.getInitParameter(CALLBACK_PARAM));
}

private String getFromSession(String param){
    return (String) this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute(param);
}

}
```

Comment: Incidentally, I don't know if this is your problem or not but, I've never seen the scope look like that for Google Calendar.  I've always seen Google Calendar OAuth scopes look like http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user%40domain/private/full See Google documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html#prepScope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently been working with oAuth.  Inside **upgradeLogin(...)** when you are upgrading to an access token you are not fetching the respective access token secret.

The access token secret following the getAccessToken() request is different to the access token secret before the request. You are currently setting the access token secret (via login.setAccessTokenSecret(oauthTS)), it is the pre-updated access token secret value you are using.  You need to set it to the access token secret value returned after the update request:

```
String accesToken = oauthHelper.getAccessToken(oauthParameters);
String accesTokenSecret = oauthParameters.getOAuthTokenSecret();                
login.setTokenSecret(accesToken);
login.setAccessTokenSecret(accesTokenSecret);
```

You also probably want to store this updated token/secret pair somewhere.  It is this value of access token secret that should then to be used inside getPublicCalendars(...) in the line:

```
oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);
```

The post update access token/secret pair is long-lived and can therefore be re-used (without needing to update it again) until such time as it is revoked.

Incidentally I found the [oAuth Playground Tool](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/) useful in diagnosing my problems.

I hope this helps,

Comment: yep, I was doing a lot of workarounds due my inexperience in GWT, GAE  even java :P I solved the problem as you said, now I have a better understand about how OAuth works. Thanks a lot!